# Returning table column names that are reserved key words?

Tags: postgresql, create-function, postgresql-9.5

I'm creating this function that returns a table. I have this issue in the 9th line in the code below, I believe the 'position' and the following 'attribute' column is the main problem. I want to return the column name exactly like in the code below. Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION acc_qry_chart_of_account ( 
  type CHARACTER (3)='GL') RETURNS TABLE ( seqno SERIAL,
        acc_id INTEGER,
        parent_code CHARACTER (20),
        acc_code CHARACTER (20),
        description CHARACTER VARYING (120),
        description2 CHARACTER VARYING (120),
        acclevel INTEGER,
        position CHARACTER VARYING (120),
        attribute INTEGER,
        acctype CHARACTER (3),
        exttype CHARACTER(3)
  )
AS $$
DECLARE
....
BEGIN
....
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Comment: You need to enclose them in double quotes: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this way. 2 changes.

- Double quote column position
- declare seqno as integer. Serial is not a datatype (it is a shortcut for using sequence)

New function:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION acc_qry_chart_of_account ( 
  type CHARACTER (3)='GL') RETURNS TABLE ( seqno integer,
        acc_id INTEGER,
        parent_code CHARACTER (20),
        acc_code CHARACTER (20),
        description CHARACTER VARYING (120),
        description2 CHARACTER VARYING (120),
        acclevel INTEGER,
        "position" CHARACTER VARYING (120),
        attribute INTEGER,
        acctype CHARACTER (3),
        exttype CHARACTER(3)
  )
AS $$
DECLARE
....
BEGIN
....
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```